# Build Project in only Debug Configuration in a Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS2012 solution which has 10 projects.The solution is build by a script for all configurations. There is one project out of the ten that I want only to be build only if the solution is built in (debug,release Internal) configuration. How can I do it in VS2012?

**Update 1**: If we have a solution which has a project which is configured only for debug mode. If we built the solution in release mode, the project builds in debug mode. The point is, I don't want it to build at all if the solution is not currently build under debug/release_internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up using the configuration manager (accessible via the last item in the active solution configuration dropdown):

[image: config manager dropdown]

Then simply uncheck the relevant "Build" checkbox for all the projects you *don't* want to build in the given solution configuration/platform (don't forget to do this for each applicable combination of solution configurations/platforms):

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for a quick reply!.