# Not having the option of of “Release” in the configuration when publishing a website

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, publish, publishing

I have already build a web application using visual studio. Now I am trying to host it using azure. I have hosted the database successfully. But I am unable to host the website. I have gone through several tutorials. In the publishing procedure there is no option of “Release” for configuration. In my case It only has the “Debug” option. So I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, when you publish an app, the setting is the same as what he set in configuration manager.

You could try to **add a new "Release" option in Configuration Manager**.

[image]

After configuring it well, once you publish the app, the "Release" option will show up.

[image]
Also, I found someone have the same problem like you, you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368605/build-project-in-only-debug-configuration-in-a-solution).

**Update:**
When you is "Debug" mode, you have the following configuration:

[image]

When you is "Release" mode, you have the following configuration:

[image]

So, you could choose **Empty** first when you set the "copy setting from". Then choose the "release" you have added and click property of project to configure it like above.

Comment: how to add a new release option. What can be used to fill the section of “copy settings from”??

Comment: I have updated my reply, and you could refer it to configure the "Release" you have added.

Comment: I have created a “release”. But I am unable to find the properties as you have shown in the last image

Comment: As you have choose a "Empty" when you create "release", click your project->Property->Build then choose "Configuration" as "release". After all, choose the option as I the last image.Save it and it was release setting.